# What reference style is this?

Tags: citation-style

Below is a reference of an article cited as footnote on a page of a book. I'm not familiar with this style so just want to know.

Anne Nguyen. Cultural and Social Attitudes Towards Mental Illness in Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam. *Stanford University Research Journal* 2003: 27-31.

And here's a reference for a book:

Richard Keller. *Colonial Madness: Psychiatry in French North Africa.* Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2007, 89.

Comment: Who is the publisher of the book? It may be a "house style."

Comment: Related question: [How to know which citation style is applied?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/87954/14341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style seems to be a slight variation to [Chicago](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html) notes style (as opposed to the bibliography style). In strict Chicago the journal article would be:

> Anne Nguyen, "Cultural and Social Attitudes Towards Mental Illness in Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam," *Stanford University Research Journal* (2003): 27-31.

With the key differences being a comma instead of a period after the author, quotes around the title followed by a comma and parenthesis around the year.

Similarly for the book it would be:

> Richard Keller, *Colonial Madness: Psychiatry in French North Africa.* (Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2007), 89.

with a comma instead of a period after the author and the press and year in parenthesis.